# How can I find a single channel image to run the method cvCanny of openCV

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, opencv, image-processing

Suppose that I have this code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv\highgui.h"
#include "opencv2\imgproc\imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2\core\core.hpp"
#include "opencv\cv.h"

using namespace cv;


IplImage* doPyrDown(IplImage*,int );
IplImage* doCanny(IplImage*,double,double,double);

int main()
{
    const char*a ="D:\\s.jpg" ;
    IplImage* in = cvLoadImage(a);
    IplImage* img1 = doPyrDown( in, IPL_GAUSSIAN_5x5 );
    IplImage* img2 = doPyrDown( img1, IPL_GAUSSIAN_5x5 );
    IplImage* img3 = doCanny( img2, 10, 100, 3 );
    cvNamedWindow("in",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvNamedWindow("img1",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvNamedWindow("img2",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvNamedWindow("img3",CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
    cvShowImage("in",in);
    cvShowImage("img1",img1);
    cvShowImage("img2",img2);
    cvShowImage("img3",img3);
    cvWaitKey(0);
    cvReleaseImage( &in );
    cvReleaseImage( &img1 );
    cvReleaseImage( &img2 );
    cvReleaseImage( &img3 );
    cvDestroyWindow("in");
    cvDestroyWindow("img1");
    cvDestroyWindow("img2");
    cvDestroyWindow("img3");
    return 0;
}




//Using cvPyrDown() to create a new image that is half the width and height of the input
//image
IplImage* doPyrDown(IplImage* in,int filter = CV_GAUSSIAN_5x5)
{
// Best to make sure input image is divisible by two.
    //
    assert( in->width%2 == 0 && in->height%2 == 0 );
    IplImage* out = cvCreateImage(cvSize( in->width/2, in->height/2 ),in->depth,in->nChannels);
    cvPyrDown( in, out );
    return( out );
}

 //The Canny edge detector writes its output to a single channel (grayscale) image
 IplImage* doCanny(IplImage* in,double lowThresh,double highThresh,double aperture)
 {
    if(in->nChannels != 1)
        return(0); //Canny only handles gray scale images
    IplImage* out = cvCreateImage(cvGetSize(in),IPL_DEPTH_8U,1);
    cvCanny( in, out, lowThresh, highThresh, aperture );
    return( out );
  }
```

This code does not have any compile error. The problem is it will not show any image in the window `img3` because it identifies all off the images that I give as a non single channel image and enters `if(in->nChannels != 1)` and runs the code `return(0);`
I have tried all of gray scale images found in my computer and searched the net for single channel images but all of them have this problem. I have put a breakpoint and tried the code step by step for all of the images that I gave??!!!!
**Could you tell me what kind of image is known as a single channel image to the openCV library and give me a link to such an image that would work with the code above?**

Comment: Try `IplImage* in = cvLoadImage(a,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the documentation [here](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/c/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html).

The definition of the function that you use to load the image is:
`IplImage* cvLoadImage(const char* filename, int iscolor=CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR)`.

It means that `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR` is used by default. If you want to load your image in grayscale, use `CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE`, as proposed in the comments:

```
IplImage* in = cvLoadImage(a,CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);
```

To summarize, **you** have to tell OpenCV if you want it to load your image as a color image or as a grayscale image. If you ask it to open a color image as a grayscale image, then OpenCV will simply convert it.